# How to make python recognize a self-written package?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, spyder

I created a package (called PyLib) and now, I want to use its content from other script files. I use macOS Catalina and Spyder which came with the Anaconda distribution. I added the absolute path for my package to sys.path:
[image]

Next, I added an `__init__.py` (which is empty) to the folder (and some content):
[image]

To verify if it works, I restarted the kernel (and Spyder, and macOS) but still my package is not recognized:
[image]

What did I forget to do? What can I do to make python recognize my package?

Comment: Does it have an __init__.py file in it?

Comment: Hi @rotten: Yes, see 2nd image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your sys.path value one directory higher to the directory that has PyLib in it instead of to PyLib itself.

Comment: Python is looking _in_ PyLib for a module called PyLib, whereas it should actually be looking in the folder above that for a module called PyLib.